# Smart randomness algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I built a small app where I can import my kindle highlights and have a few ones sent to me daily by email. The issue is that I often receive the same highlights, so I think the way I did it is not optimal.

```
  const highlights = [....] // an array of strings with all my highlights (couple hundreds)

  const indices = [];

  // choosing 5 random highlights indices
  while (indices.length < 5)) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * highlights.length);
    indices.push(random);
  }
```

I would expect that with a couple of hundreds of highlights, there's a low probability of receiving the same, but I am apparently wrong?

My knowledge of algorithms is close to zero. Is there any algo I could use here? Or is it better to save in the database the nb of times a highlight has been sent to cover them all?

Comment: Looks ok to me. But if you are not sure, simply write  a test to check if the probability of collisions is higher than expected.

Comment: If you can't /do not want to store which highlights you have already sent, you could at least ensure (by checking or using a set)  that the 5, you are currently picking, are different.

Comment: Obligatory: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: I tested the code above. The probability is indeed quite low among the 5. 
But repeat a few times, e.g. 25 selections out of 200 possibilities. Then the probability of finding one pair is pretty high (related to "Birthday paradox").  
But it's not really "often" (e.g. just one pair among so many selections), relatively speaking. I wonder if something actually changed the length of your highlights.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to retrieve X unique elements from a array is to shuffle it and then take the first x elements.
the [Durstenfeld shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) is easy to implements if your language doesn't have a built-in way of shuffling an array.